# Ways to improve this loop to do it more pythonizable

Tags: python, python-3.5

I need to operate between columns and rows. I developed some code base in "for" loop. I understand that using dataframe operations (panda) could perform better, I tried differents but it didn´t work. Maybe you can help me.

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if i == 1:
        df['A'][i] = df['D'][i]
    elif df['B'][i] == 1:
        df['A'][i] = df['A'].shift()[i] + df['C'][i]
    elif df['B'][i] == 0:
        df['A'][i] = df['A'].shift()[i]
```

Source:

```
Date        B   D    X  C   A   
2004-03-03  0.0 1122 59 0.0 0.0 
2004-03-03  0.0 1151 59 0.0 0.0
2004-03-04  0.0 1154 68 0.0 0.0 
2004-03-05  0.0 1156 72 0.0 0.0 
2004-03-08  0.0 1147 38 0.0 0.0 
2004-03-09  0.0 1140 27 0.0 0.0 
2004-03-10  0.0 1123 13 0.0 0.0 
2004-03-11  0.0 1106 8  0.0 0.0 
2004-03-12  1.0 1120 36 14  0.0 
2004-03-15  1.0 1104 24 -16 0.0 
2004-03-16  1.0 1110 35 6   0.0 
2004-03-17  1.0 1123 53 13  0.0
```

Result:

```
Date        B   D    X  C   A   
2004-03-02  0.0 1122 59 0.0 1122    
2004-03-03  0.0 1151 59 0.0 1122    
2004-03-04  0.0 1154 68 0.0 1122    
2004-03-05  0.0 1156 72 0.0 1122    
2004-03-08  0.0 1147 38 0.0 1122    
2004-03-09  0.0 1140 27 0.0 1122    
2004-03-10  0.0 1123 13 0.0 1122    
2004-03-11  0.0 1106 8  0.0 1122    
2004-03-12  1.0 1120 36 14  1135    
2004-03-15  1.0 1104 24 -16 1118    
2004-03-16  1.0 1110 35 6   1124    
2004-03-17  1.0 1123 53 13  1137
```

Comment: Please post what you tried & what specifically was wrong with it.

Comment: Could you do something like

Comment: Scott, thanks for the answer. The code works fine, I am trying to improve it using more python friendly code. Something like Robin answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```py
df[A] = (df['A'] == 1) * (df['A'].shift() + df['C']) + df['A'].shift()[i] + (df['A'] == 0)
df['A'][0] = df['D'][1]
```

It would not use a loop but I assume it would be faster. I replaced `i = 1` by `i = 0` because indexing in pandas dataframes starts from 0 not 1

Comment: Robin, Thanks for the answer. I´will try it and comeback with feedback!! Regards!